# How do I put different plugins in one chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I made one chart area that has two charts. I just want to set data labels positions different of these two charts.

[chart problem example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obz1E.png)

So I set the code like this

```
 export const radardata2 = {
    labels: [
        '1',
        '2',
        '3',
        '4',
        '5'
    ],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: 'This week',
            borderColor: '#d90429',
            data: radarData1,
        },
        {
            label: 'Last week',
            borderColor: '#390099',
            data: radarData2,
        },
    ],
};
```

```
export let radarchartOptions2 = {
        responsive: true,
        tooltips: false,
        scales: {
            
            r : {
                beginAtZero: true,
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                pointLabels: {
                    font:{
                        size: 15,
                        weight: "bold"
                    },
                    
                },
                ticks: {
                    display: false
                },
                
                
                },

            },
        plugins: {
                
            datalabels: {
                font: {
                    size : 20
                },
                anchor: 'end',
                align: 'start',
                offset: 10,
            }
                
            },  
        }
```

I just want to make the labels position different because they overlap and it makes to see the result data hard.
In x or y axis I saw there was YID or XID things. Is there plugin id in chart js?

Comment: [These](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/radial/linear.html#point-label-options) are all the options for pointLabels, I can't see any option to change the position, other than `centerPointLabels`, but I don't if the result will be what you want, if you set it to true.

Comment: Maybe you can configure the datalabels plugin at dataset level, using different configuration and values for anchor, align and offset, in order to avoid the overlapping.

Comment: Here is the doc: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#configuration